# Maven separate Unit Test and Integration Tests

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

UT = Unit Tests
IT = Integration Tests. All my Integration test classes are annotated with @Category(IntegrationTest.class)

My goal is:

`mvn clean install` => runs UT and not IT

`mvn clean install` -DskipTests=true => no tests are executed

`mvn clean deploy` => runs UT and not IT

`mvn clean test` => runs UT and not IT

`mvn clean verify` => runs UT and IT

`mvn clean integration-test` => runs IT and UT are not executed

`mvn clean install deploy` => runs UT and not IT

pom properties:

```
<junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
<surefire-plugin.version>2.18.1</surefire-plugin.version>
<failsafe-plugin.version>2.18.1</failsafe-plugin.version>
```

1. Compiler:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.1</version>
       <configuration>
           <source>1.8</source>
           <target>1.8</target>
           <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
           <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
           <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. Unit Tests:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
       <configuration>
           <excludedGroups>com.xpto.IntegrationTest</excludedGroups>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. Integration Tests:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>${failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
       <configuration>
           <groups>com.xpto.IntegrationTest</groups>
       </configuration>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <goals>
                   <goal>integration-test</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                   <includes>
                       <include>**/*.class</include>
                   </includes>
               </configuration>
           </execution>                
       </executions>              
   </plugin>
   ```

My results are:

`mvn clean install` => OK

`mvn clean install` -DskipTests=true => OK

`mvn clean deploy` => runs UT and not IT

`mvn clean test` => OK

`mvn clean verify` => NOK ... only UT are executed but IT also needs to be executed

`mvn clean integration-test` => NOK ... UT are executed and should not and IT aren't executed but should be executed

`mvn clean install deploy` => OK

Comment: Is it possible for you to add some sample tests? Perhaps a UT and IT. I'm wondering if how they are named/organized/annotated is part of the issue.

Comment: At least part of your requirements will probably not be doable ... you say "mvn clean integration-test" should run IT and *not* UT, but the maven lifecycle is a chain ... when you run `mvn integration-test` it runs through generate-sources, compile, compile-test, test, package, etc all the way up to and including integration-test. Your UT should be super-quick anyway, so why would you want to skip them?

Comment: First i would suggest to use the correct naming convention to name a unit test `*Test.java` and integration tests `*IT.java` (see docs of maven-surefire-plugin/maven-failsafe-plugin). Furthermore if you do a thing like this : `mvn clean install deploy` this does not make sense and didn't understand the maven build life cycle. If you do `mvn deploy` the install is part of the life cycle which in result means just use `mvn deploy`. If a call `mvn clean deploy` will run your UT but not IT's your configuration is wrong.

Comment: I'm using Naming conventions for maven-surefire-plugin (unit tests). Naming conventions for maven-failsafe-plugin (integration tests) as suggested and It's working perfectly with khmarbaise solution. But now my Integration Tests are not intercepted by the cobertura plugin. Any suggestion? Maybe using JaCoCo instead?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The solution is this:

```xml
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>${surefire.skip}</skip>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

This will let you control which is executed.

running UT and IT's:

```
mvn clean verify
```

running IT's but NOT UT's

```
mvn clean verify -Dsurefire.skip=true
```

running UT but not IT's:

```
mvn clean verify -DskipITs=true
```

You need to follow the naming conventions of the plugins which makes life easier.

[Naming conventions](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) for maven-surefire-plugin (unit tests).
[Naming conventions](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) for maven-failsafe-plugin (integration tests).

Comment: It's working perfectly now. But now my Integration Tests are not intercepted by the cobertura plugin. Any suggestion? Maybe using JaCoCo instead?

Comment: For [cobertura-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/) i would suggest to look into the documentation of you can use JaCoCo ?...

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349864/merging-integration-and-unit-test-reports-with-jacoco

Comment: Is this right? maven-surefire-plugin has only a test goal. It has neither integration-test nor a verify goal.

When I run the example it throws an error:

`Could not find goal 'integration-test' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1 among available goals.` I am using **Apache Maven 3.6.0**

Comment: The integration tests should be run with Maven Failsafe Plugin instead... https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html