# Jacoco coverage of unit and integration tests combined with coverageratio

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage, jacoco

In my project I use Jacoco plugin to show coverage report of unit tests,as well as integration tests,and one report which shows combined code coverage.Now I want to set coverageratio for that combined coverage,but my build is now failing because Jacoco only look for unit code coverage,not combined,which is smaller,of course, than specified report of combined.
Am I missing something in pom.xml?
Here is my configuration in pom.xml regarding to coverageratio:

```
<execution>
                            <id>default-check</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>check</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <rules>
                                    <rule>
                                        <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                        <limits>
                                            <limit>
                                                <counter>LINE</counter>
                                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                                <minimum>0.80</minimum>
                                            </limit>
                                        </limits>
                                    </rule>
                                </rules>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: Maybe more nice way is to achieve is use the same file, but let it append another test, which works for us - unit and it tests.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${maven.surefire.skipTests}</skip>
                <propertyName>maven.surefire.argLine</propertyName>
                <!-- using the same dest file for both UT and IT -->
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent-integration</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${maven.failsafe.skipTests}</skip>
                <propertyName>maven.failsafe.argLine</propertyName>
                <!-- append to the UT dest file -->
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>${maven.surefire.skipTests}</skipTests>
        <failIfNoTests>${maven.surefire.failIfNoTests}</failIfNoTests>
        <!-- allow argLine to be modified by other plugins, e.g. jacoco -->
        <argLine>@{maven.surefire.argLine}</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>${maven.failsafe.skipTests}</skipTests>
        <failIfNoTests>${maven.failsafe.failIfNoTests}</failIfNoTests>
        <!-- allow argLine to be modified by other plugins, e.g. jacoco -->
        <argLine>@{maven.failsafe.argLine}</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Original text: I got inspired [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349864/merging-integration-and-unit-test-reports-with-jacoco/41625080) as well [in this blog](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/) resulting in following code, where is visible, that is measured coverage of unit tests, integration tests, then result is merged and only for whole bundle (not individual classes) it fails, if coverage is less than 70%.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                        <propertyName>testArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>merge-results</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>merge</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <fileSets>
                            <fileSet>
                                <directory>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*.exec</include>
                                </includes>
                            </fileSet>
                        </fileSets>
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/aggregate.exec</destFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-merge-report</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/aggregate.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-aggregate</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/aggregate.exec</dataFile>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.70</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.70</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>com.xyz.ClassToExclude</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*UT.java</include>
                    <include>**/*MT.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
                <skipTests>${skipUTMTs}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                <skipITs>${skipITs}</skipITs>
                <argLine>${testArgLine}</argLine>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*UT*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, having Jacoco write two files, one for the unit tests and other for integration tests, then merging these two files and generating the report from the single merged file as follows did:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.4</version>
    <executions>

      <execution>
        <id>prepare-agent</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
        </configuration>
      </execution>

      <execution>
        <id>prepare-agent-integration</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-integration.exec</destFile>
          <append>true</append>
        </configuration>
      </execution>

      <execution>
        <id>report</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>merge</goal>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <!-- merge config -->
          <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</destFile>
          <fileSets>
            <fileSet>
              <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>*.exec</include>
              </includes>
            </fileSet>
          </fileSets>
          <!-- report config -->
          <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
        </configuration>
      </execution>

    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: The same for me, merging the files worked fine.