# Is it possible to get combined test coverage of android Unitesting and UI testing coverage | not repeated question

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-espresso, ui-testing

I have tried using **jacoco** for fetching code coverage but every time i am able to get 100% success  also i have found that **JacocoEverywhere** is deprecated is there any other way to fetch code coverage.

I have gone through several stackoverflow questions not able to find the answer so raising this question.

Comment: This is difficult to answer without knowing what your setup is i.e. the pipeline or whatever process you are using to generate coverage. Generally, in order to produce coverage, your code needs to be instrumented, that means counters need to be added to the source code, which is not something you'd want in a production artefact, which UI tests are usually run against... There is the option to merge Jacoco generated reports, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349864/merging-integration-and-unit-test-reports-with-jacoco