# Splitting unit and integration tests with Maven

Tags: maven, unit-testing, jenkins, testing, integration-testing

I'm setting up a CD pipeline in Jenkins and I want to run my unit tests and integration tests in two different steps. The plan is to have my pipeline script look something like this and have them run separately:

```
    stage('Unit tests') {
        steps {
            withMaven(maven: 'Maven 3.6.2') {
                sh 'mvn test -P coverage'
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Integration tests') {
        steps {
            withMaven(maven: 'Maven 3.6.2') {
                sh 'mvn test -P coverage'
            }
        }
```

I have tried using the surefire plugin as described here: https://dzone.com/articles/splitting-unit-and-integration-tests-using-maven-a, and running 'mvn test' does run only the unit test as it should, but 'mvn integration-test' runs both unit and integration tests.

I have also tried using the failsafe plugin as described here: [Maven separate Unit Test and Integration Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308037/maven-separate-unit-test-and-integration-tests), but 'mvn verify' runs both unit and integration tests no matter which options I enter.

How can I make my pipeline execute the unit tests and integration tests in two different steps?

Pom with surefire:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> <!-- surefire plugin version managed by Spring Boot -->
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unit-tests</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IT.*</include>
                            <include>**/*Tests.*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Pom with surefire and failsafe:

```
            <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${surefire.skip}</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: Could you provide example pom.xml or better an example project ( with example code ) ?

Comment: Why do you like to separate them? Running units should be done always...sometimes it might needed to have running integration tests separately usually done via maven-failsafe-plugin and using `mvn clean verify -Prun-its` (profile only if your integration tests take very long time) ...Do not use maven-surefire-plugin to run integration tests...follow convention and use unit tests name `*Test.java` whereas integration tests name `*IT.java`(details in the docs) ...do not configure surefire in the way you are doing cause there existing very good defaults...which is in 99.999% of the cases correct.

Comment: Both unit and integration tests will be run every build, but we would like to separate them to have better control of where things fail.

Comment: As I wrote ...using naming conventions correctly and you can control via `mvn clean test` running unit tests and via `mvn clean verfiy`(may be supplemental `-Prun-its` to run also integration tests..

Comment: Do not bind maven-surefire-plugin to integration-test part this is intended with maven-failsafe-plugin ...

Comment: Okay. So I did as you recommended @khmarbaise, my pom now includes the surefire and failsafe plugin as they are by default, I have included nothing extra. Running `mvn clean test` now runs only unit tests, but `mvn clean verify` runs both. How can I make `verify` run only integration tests?

Comment: What is the problem with running unit tests?

Comment: It's not needed to run them twice, like I said during our build we run `mvn clean test` which should perform only unit tests, and directly after `mvn clean verify` which should run only integration tests. As it is now, the unit tests will be run both during `test` and `verify`

Comment: Couldn't you run the failsafe plugin separately?

Comment: My question is: Why would you like to separate those things? And why would like to run the whole process two times? Cause each time you run `mvn clean test` or `mvn clean verify` things like compiling etc. is done two time? So I don't see the advantage of preventing running the unit tests?

Answer (score 4):

This solved it for me:

Below is example pom.xml which works with the following commands:

- `mvn clean verify -DskipUTs=true` : Runs only integration tests (tests ending in "IT")
- `mvn clean verify -DskipITs=true` : Runs only unit tests (tests ending in "Test")
- `mvn clean verify -DskipTests=true` : Skips all tests

  ```
  <build>
  <finalName>test-app</finalName>
  <plugins>

      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> <!-- surefire plugin version managed by Spring Boot -->
          <configuration>
              <skipTests>${skipUTs}</skipTests>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <id>run-integration-tests</id>
                  <phase>integration-test</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>integration-test</goal>
                      <goal>verify</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
              <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
              <skipITs>${skipITs}</skipITs>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>

  </plugins>
  </build>
  ```